# Maximum entropy function, with f(0)=0?

Tags: distributions, maximum-entropy

I want to derive the Maximum Entropy distribution (f(x)) with the following constraints: 1. non-negative 2. specified mean 3. specified variance 4. f(0)=0 I know how to derive the MaxEnt distro with constraints (1) to (3), but I am not sure how to incorporate (4). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: (4) is meaningless because individual values of probability densities are not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Well, I think the key thing here is not the value at a single point, but that the function tends to 0 for sufficiently small x. Since f(x) is continous we can write f(x) = 0 for short.

Comment: Continuity of $f$ is a (strong) assumption.  For instance, uniform distributions never have densities that are everywhere continuous.  Unfortunately, it's also not a useful assumption, because it doesn't restrict $f$ beyond an infinitesimal neighborhood of $0.$ If you could supply restrictions on the rate at which $f$ tends to $0,$ that might lead to a solvable problem.